# Flutter Web | Create .vcf file (vCard) and download it

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

Flutter Web | Create .vcf file (vCard) and download it.
ive been searching for a while and reading a lot of discussion but still no clear solution. already tried searching in pub.dev and all that is available is for the IOS and Android.

Comment: Is your question how to construct a .vcf with data you already have, or to get contact information in order to make a .vcf?

Comment: Hello @DanHarms thank you for your response. i have done the vcard template and also able to download the file now. my current problem is. is there a way to automatically open the add contact of the phone provided with data then the user will just save it?